How to Cancel Previous Requests When Making New Requests in React with RTK Query (without using useQuery)
I'm working with React and RTK Query and I'm trying to figure out how to cancel previous requests if a new one is being made (like when a user switches pages or makes another request while the previous one is still loading).
I have a getUsers query that looks like this:
const { data: userData, isFetching: userIsFetching, isError: userIsError, error: userError, refetch: userRefetch, } = useGetUserQuery({ from, to }, { skip: !(from && to) });
this code is inside dashboard component.
And the API method is set up like this:
getUsers: build.query<IUser>({ query: () => ({ url: 'api-url-here', }), }),
and this code is inside user-slice.ts file.
The from and to values may change based on the calendar. If the user selects new from and to dates, and they do so repeatedly without waiting for the response from the previous request, we need to cancel the previous requests and only show the result of the last request.
I believe I should handle this inside a function where I capture the from and to values. However, I’m not entirely sure how to implement this.
What I want to do is cancel the previous request if there’s a new one coming in. I know I can use an AbortController to add a signal to the request, but I’m not sure how to implement that properly with RTK Query. Does anyone have any suggestions or examples?

What is your intention behind cancelling the request? Wouldn't it be positive if the request kept going and if the user navigated back a page they already had the data instead of making yet another request?

@phry Since there are many pages, users can switch between them without waiting for the previous response. They might do this casually or just for fun, without paying attention to the content. This could result in a lot of unnecessary requests. I’d like to handle this scenario effectively.

The request has gone to the server already, and the server has already started processing. That happens so fast that you can't avoid it. I would check with your server implementation if it even can stop a request if the connection is closed before investigating this further - most server implementations will probably not do that.

@phry actually it is possible to do that. I have seen some examples with useQuery or AbortSignal/AbortController. However, in my case I am not sure how to use them

Of course it is possible to tell your browser to stop listening to the response of a request. But that doesn't time-travel back and stops the browser from making a request to the server. And it also doesn't stop the server from processing the request in most cases. It only stops the browser from receiving the response - but the chance is that the server still fully generates the response, even if nobody listens to it.

I'm trying to find an analogy: if you throw a dart and then close your eyes, the dart still keeps flying. You won't know the number you scored, but the dart left your hands, is flying and will hit the target. Using an AbortController is "closing your eyes" - you won't get the result. But everything else still happens. Some servers can detect that the connection was closed and will stop processing, but e.g. a normal express server won't do that. All the code on the server will still run to completion.
